# Convert hex to INT 32 and STRING Little Endian

Tags: java, json, hex, converters

First question:

Hex: F1620000

After convert hex to INT 32 i expect 253229, but i get -245235712.
I've tried these methods:

```
Integer.parseUnsignedInt(value, 16));
(int)Long.parseLong(value, 16));
new BigInteger(value, 16).intValue());
```

How i can get correct value?

Second question:

Hex: 9785908D9B9885828020912E208D2E

After covert hex to STRING i can get this value:

```
\u0097\u0085\u0090\u008d\u009b\u0098\u0085\u0082\u0080 \u0091. \u008d.
```

How can I display this value correctly in json? (usning JSONObject).

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i += 2) {
    String str = value.substring(i, i + 2);
      result.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
  }
```

Comment: This is a hex value, I need to convert the hex value to a value that is a string

Comment: I added the code with which I got this string.

Comment: You can use this converter for F1620000 https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/

Comment: I want get "Чернышева С. Н."

Comment: Please add [this last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337195/convert-hex-to-int-32-and-string-little-endian/60337968#comment106732682_60337195) to your question for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your attempts are sufficient for parsing a hexadecimal string in an unsigned interpretation, but did not account for the “little endian” representation. You have to reverse the bytecode manually:

```
String value = "F1620000";
int i = Integer.reverseBytes(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(value, 16));
System.out.println(i);
```

```
25329
```

For your second task, the missing information was how to interpret the bytes to get to the character content. After searching a bit, the [Codepage 866](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866) seems to be the most plausible encoding:

```
String value = "9785908D9B9885828020912E208D2E";
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(value, 16).toByteArray();
String result = new String(bytes, bytes[0]==0? 1: 0, value.length()/2, "CP866");
```

```
ЧЕРНЫШЕВА С. Н.
```